# XML Deserialization not working past the first element

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I am attempting to use XML deserialization to convert a XML response from a host into C# objects.  The root element is converted into its object and the 2nd element appears to be converted, but it's an empty element anyway.  Beyond that, non of the other elements are converted.  What am I missing?

I have tried many different variations of objects for each element and arrays of elements (even though an array is not needed.  I even found that you can paste the XML into the editor in Visual Studio and it will create the serialized objects (edit, paste special, Paste XML As Classes), but I have not been able to get anything to work!

Here's how the XML looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE paymentService PUBLIC "-//MySite/DTD MySite PaymentService v1//EN" "http://dtd.mysite.com/paymentService_v1.dtd">
<paymentService version="1.4" merchantCode="ExampleCode1">
    <reply>
        <orderStatus orderCode="ExampleOrder1">
            <reference id="YourReference">https://payments-test.mysite.com/app/hpp/integration/wpg/corporate?OrderKey=NGPPTESTMERCH1%5Ejsxml3835829684&amp;Ticket=00146321872957902pqKhCTUf0vajKCw-X5HqZA</reference>
        </orderStatus>
    </reply>
</paymentService>
```

-OR-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE paymentService PUBLIC "-//MySite//DTD MySite PaymentService v1//EN" "http://dtd.MySite.com/paymentService_v1.dtd">
<paymentService version="1.4" merchantCode="ExampleCode1">
   <reply>
      <orderStatus orderCode="ExampleOrder1">
         <error code="2">
            <![CDATA[Invalid address: Postal code is missing or empty.]]>
        </error>
      </orderStatus>
   </reply>
</paymentService>
```

Here are the objects:

```
   [Serializable]
   [XmlRoot(ElementName = "paymentService")]
   public partial class PaymentResponse
   {
      [XmlAttribute()]
      public string version { get; set; }

      [XmlAttribute()]
      public string merchantCode { get; set; }

      [XmlElement("reply")]
      public Reply reply { get; set; }
   }
   [Serializable]
   public partial class Reply
   {
      [XmlElement("orderStatus")]
      public OrderStatus orderStatus {get; set; }
   }
   [Serializable]
   public partial class OrderStatus
   {
         [XmlAttribute()]
         public string orderCode {get; set; }

         [XmlElement(ElementName = "reference",IsNullable =true)]
         public Reference reference {get; set; }

         [XmlElement(ElementName = "error",IsNullable =true)]
         public Error error {get; set; }
   }
```

Here's the call to do the deserialization:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PaymentResponse));
        PaymentResponse response = (PaymentResponse)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

The only thing that is returned in the merchantcode and version from PaymentResponse.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to tell the serializer about what to do about with the your non-primative types.

Try changing this

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "reference",IsNullable =true)]
public Reference reference {get; set; }

[XmlElement(ElementName = "error",IsNullable =true)]
public Error error {get; set; }
```

to this

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "reference", Type = typeof(Reference), IsNullable = true)]
public Reference reference {get; set; }

[XmlElement(ElementName = "error", Type = typeof(Error), IsNullable = true)]
public Error error {get; set; }
```

Good Luck!